# Limit forum access to the administrator in a drupal website

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

as i'm currently building a forum on my website, I don't want any person other than me to see the forum (well not until it is done). What can I do to block access to the forum ? (Drupal module is advanced forum)
Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Forum Access](http://drupal.org/project/forum_access) module, for Drupal 7 it's still in beta, but it should do the job. Plus check out this post about [Private forums in Drupal](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/private-forums-in-drupal-forum-access-vs-taxonomy-access-vs-taxonomy-access-control-lite) by Lullabot.